# call a function include pointer

Tags: c, pointers

suppose we got a void function include pointers:
`void order(double *smp, double *lgp)`

when we call the function in main, it's
`order(&num1, &num2);`

My question is when we define the function, it is "`double *`", which means its a value of the pointee. But when we call the function, it's "`&num1`", which is address of num1. How do they match up?

Is it the same as when we define pointer:
`double *p = &value;`, just memorize it?

Comment: What do you mean with *which means its a value of the pointee*?

Comment: what????  what's a "void function include pointers"?   double* is a double pointer, what's a "value of the pointee"?  Makes no sense.

Comment: I think in `void order(double *smp, double *lgp)`, `double *smp` means we define pointer called smp point to a pointee?

Comment: no it means the first parameter smp is a double pointer.

Comment: yes, but when we call the function why we use `&num1`, which means the address of num1?

Comment: Please read about pointers, specifically what is a pointer?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are often confusing because when you're defining it:

> double *smp

It means "smp is a variable that'll contain an double's address"

But later when you do

> *smp

It means "I want the value of the double pointed by the address contained in smp".

Here you're mixing both: the meaning are very different even though it's the same syntax.
So when you're defining your function, the * character does NOT mean it's a value in this case, it just means it's a pointer that'll receive an address.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` has different meanings based on where it's used. When in a variable definition it's not dereferencing the pointer (getting the value it's pointing to), it's saying that it is a pointer to the specfied type.

```
double *p = &value; // * is used to declare a pointer
printf("%f", *p);   // * is used to get the value p is pointing to
int i = 2*3;        // * is used as a multiplication operator
```

Comment: THX that makes a lot more sense to me.
So when we define a pointer, `*` is just to show we are defining a pointer.
In `void order(double *smp, double *lgp)`, both parameters are addresses, and when we call the function, `order(&num1, &num2);` they are still adress.
Thanks!@Jammerx2